# Internet explorer 10 and top.window.pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-10

I use `window.pageYOffset` to find the position of the scroll bar (works fine in firefox), however it is always undefined in IE10

I have tried using:

```
window.pageYOffset // undefined
document.body.scrollTop // always 0
document.documentElement.scrolltop // undefined
top.window.scrollY // undefined
```

is this a known issue with IE10?

this is with compatibility mode enabled. Without it, pageYOffset works as expected. We have to use compatibility mode as it's a requirement for our clients

the code displays a calander, which needs to be displayed against a text box. it's position is altered when the user has scrolled on the page:
UPDATED WITH CODE:

```
function showCalendar(e, datePicker) {
    top.calendarReturnFunc = function(value, controlId) {
        getDatePicker(controlId).dateBox.hasDate = "True";
        dateChosen(value, controlId, true);
    };
    top.datePickerActive = function() { return true; };
    var itop = top.window.screenTop != undefined ? top.window.screenTop : parseInt(top.window.screenY) + parseInt(130);
    var ileft = top.window.screenLeft != undefined ? top.window.screenLeft : parseInt(top.window.screenX);


    var x = e.screenX - parseInt(ileft);
    var y;

    if (typeof top.window.pageYOffset === "undefined") {
        y = (e.screenY - parseInt(itop) - datePicker.yOffset) + document.documentElement.scrollTop; //IE10?...
    }
    else {
        y = (e.screenY - parseInt(itop) - datePicker.yOffset) + top.window.pageYOffset; //works fine in firefox
    }

    if (datePicker.alignLeft) {
        x -= 180;
    }
    if (!datePicker.alignBottom) {
        y -= 178;
    }
    _calendar.style.left = x + "px";
    _calendar.style.top = y + "px";
    _calendar.style.display = "block";
    _calendar.datePicker = datePicker;
    _calendar.callingFrame = this;
    _calendar.src = datePicker.calendarUrl + "&Date=" + escape(datePicker.dateBox.value);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.top.scrollY` ?

Comment: Yeh just tried that, still undefined. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: `window.pageYOffset` works for me in IE10.

Comment: ^ for me it's always set to '0' which is not correct

Comment: might i add, this is with compatibility mode enabled (we have to use this, as this is how our is set up)

Comment: anyone? i'm really struggling with this. None of the solutions work with compatibility mode enabled

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for IE. You didn’t capitalise the T in scrollTop in your sample.

Comment: can you provide a link to your page or a jsfiddle demo? It should work correctly, so maybe something else is getting in the way. You can confirm it by opening F12 dev tools on any page and running it in the console.

Comment: i have provided my code, please see the lines where i'm calculating value y

Comment: I mean a link where we can run the code. Will make it much easier to debug.